# How to transfere data from one function to another using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xml, function

Hey everybody I have a problem.
I am building a website and I want to fetch data from two different xml files with two different functions.
ShowResult is used to get a game score and the name of a specific user.
GiveFeedback also needs the score from the first function to fetch a fitting feedback about this score from a different xml file.

I don´t get an error Message. My only problem is that the second function (giveFeedback) isn´t able to fetch data from the xml because it needs a variable (score) from the first function (showResults). Both functions work on their own but I am unable to “transfer” the score data from showResults to giveFeedback.
How can I transfer the score data to the function GiveFeedback or is there a better way to resolve this problem?
Thanks!

i tried some solutions (global variable, inserting the first function in the second,..) which were already posted but unfortunately i didn´t managed to get it running.

```
<script>    

var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    showResult(xhttp.responseXML); 
    }
}; 
xhttp.open("GET", "user.xml", true); 
xhttp.send();


function showResult(xml) {  

    var name = "";
    var score = ""; 

    path1 = "/userdb/user/name";
    path2 = "/userdb/user/score";

    var nodes = xml.evaluate(path1, xml, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null); var result = nodes.iterateNext();
    name = result.childNodes[0].nodeValue;

    var nodes = xml.evaluate(path2, xml, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null); var result = nodes.iterateNext();
    //Thats wehere the variable (score) is, which i need for the second function (giveFeedback)
    score = result.childNodes[0].nodeValue;

    document.getElementById("user").innerHTML = "Congratulations " + name + ", you made " + score; 

}



var xhttp2 = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
xhttp2.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        givefeedback(xhttp2.responseXML); 
    }
}; 
xhttp2.open("GET", "feedback.xml", true); 
xhttp2.send();


function givefeedback(xml) { 

    var feedback = "";
    // This is where it´s needed
    if (score > 1){
        path = "/feedback/congratulations[percentage=25]/text";
    }

    else if (score > 8){
        path = "/feedback/congratulations[percentage=50]/text";
    }

    var nod = xml.evaluate(path, xml, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null); 
    var res = nod.iterateNext();
    feedback = res.childNodes[0].nodeValue;


    document.getElementById("feedback").innerHTML = feedback; 
}
</script>
```

Comment: You have unbalanced braces. Could you also edit your question and indent your code properly? Could you also add what exactly doesn't work? Error message?

Comment: I hope it´s better now. 

I don´t get an error Message. My only problem is that the second function (giveFeedback) isn´t able to fetch data from the xml because it needs a variable (score) from the first function (showResults).
Both functions work on their own but I am unable to “transfer” the score data from showResults to giveFeedback.

Answer (score 0):

i managed to resolve my problem.

first of all i had to declare a global variable outside the functions.
Then i had to convert the fetched variable (score) to a Number.